# Django Rest Framework overwrite serializer "to_internal_value" fucntion gets "this field is required" error with form-data, but not with json

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I want my nested serializer works like primary key related field when used as input, and works as normal nested serializer when used as output. So I overwrite the `to_internal_value`, but it only works with `application/json`. When using `form-data` and `x-www-form-urlencoded`, I got a `This field is required` error.

Here's my code for serializers.

```
class PrimaryKeyFieldMixin(object):

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        model = self.Meta.model
        try:
            return model.objects.get(pk=data)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            self.fail('does_not_exist', pk_value=data)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            self.fail('incorrect_type', data_type=type(data).__name__)

class PatientSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name=namespace + ':patient-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = '__all__'

class PatientRelatedField(PrimaryKeyFieldMixin, PatientSerializer):
    pass

class PatientRecordSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name=namespace + ':patient_records-detail')
    patient = PatientRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = PatientRecord
        fields = '__all__'
```

Using with `json`:

Request:

```
{
    "patient": 1,
    "record_data": "some data"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "url": record_url,
    "patient": {
        "url": patient_url,
        "patient_data": some_data,
    },
    "record_data": "some_data"
}
```

This works exactly as I want. But when using `form-data` and `x-www-form-urlencoded` I got a `This field is required` error on `patient` field.

After using the debug in pycharm to step through the code, it looks like I need to overwrite `get_value` function as well, I'm not sure.